Rafa-eydain in Salah: Reward and Prophet's Practice
Is there any hadith that mentions the reward of performing 70 times the prayers with Rafa-eydain (raising hands) during salah? If there is, kindly share the name of the book and reference. Also, did the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), the last Messenger of Allah, perform salah with Rafa-eydain in his final days?
